# Create custom java timer from c++ timer

Tags: java, android, c++, timer

I have the following implementation of a c++ custom timer, courtesy of a user from http://www.cplusplus.com/ who's post I cannot find right now.

```
struct timer
{
    typedef std::chrono::steady_clock clock;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;

    void reset() { start = clock::now(); }

    unsigned long long ms_ellapsed() const
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(clock::now() - start).count();
    }

private: clock::time_point start = clock::now();
};
```

I use it in a while loop to check if x ms have ellapsed, and if so, reset to 0 ms. Here is an example:

```
  timer t;
  while(true) {
     if (t.ms_ellapsed() > 5133) {
            t.reset();
    }
  }
```

I want to create a similar implementation in java for an android project, but am unfamiliar with java timers. I found this code snippet of a java timer implementation:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
     public void run() {
        // do your work 
     }
 }, 0, 60*1000);
```

Is this java implementation what I should be using to emulate the c++ timer? If so, what do I need to add to get the same functionality as the c++ timer. If not, what is a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for.  The example snippet you provided only runs the timer every minute (60 * 1000), this example runs every 100 ms and may provide better fidelity if that is what you are looking for. It will not be as fast as the C++ example which runs an infinite loop as fast as it can, but you can shorten `POLLING_PERIOD_MS` to compensate.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class TimerExample {
    private static final int POLLING_PERIOD_MS = 100;
    private static final int RESET_PERIOD_MS = 5133;

    private static long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void reset() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static long ms_ellapsed() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (TimerExample.ms_ellapsed() > RESET_PERIOD_MS) {
                    TimerExample.reset();
                }
            }
        }, 0, POLLING_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!